# Context not set in time after fetching it from the basesites request after Upgrading to 2.1

Tags: spartacus-storefront

we have our Spartacus project set up to fetch the context from the basesites request. A sample response can be seen here:

```
{
   "baseSites" : [ {
      "defaultLanguage" : {
         "isocode" : "sl"
      },
      "geoRecommended" : false,
      "showTeaser" : true,
      "stores" : [ {
         "currencies" : [ {
            "isocode" : "EUR"
         } ],
         "defaultCurrency" : {
            "isocode" : "EUR"
         },
         "defaultLanguage" : {
            "isocode" : "sl"
         },
         "languages" : [ {
            "isocode" : "sl"
         } ],
      } ],
      "uid" : "ung-site-si",
      "urlEncodingAttributes" : [ "languageCountry" ],
      "urlPatterns" : [ "(?i)^https?://localhost(:[\\d]+)?/rest/.*$", "(?i)^https?://[^/]+/(sl-SI)/?.*$" ]
   }, ...
]
```

We have two basesites set up at the moment. The urlPatterns are used to find the correct baseSite. Then the context(baseSite, language, currency) is set in our custom occ-loaded-config-converter. So we are not using any static context or fetching it from the URL, but getting the context from the response of the basesites request.

The site-context-interceptor then subscribes to e.g. this.languageService.getActive() and then sets the correct context (language, currency) for the backend requests:

```
/rest/v2/ung-site-rs/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=/shoppster-akcija&lang=sr&curr=RSD
```

Before the Spartacus Upgrade to 2.0 this worked fine. Right after the context was set from the basesites request, the subscription in the site-context-interceptor was triggered an the right context sent with the subsequent backend requests. Now after upgrading to 2.1, the context is not set on time anymore. So the first few backend requests are sent with the wrong context (default USD, en) and then at some point in time, the subscriptions are triggered an the correct context is set.

This may be related to this change:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/technical-changes-version-2/#context-change-action-not-dispatched-on-the-initial-setting-of-the-value

Is it now not possible anymore to use the basesites request to set the context?

Comment: Could you specify exact patch version you're using, please? `2.1.4`?

Comment: We are currently using 2.1.1

Comment: Did you upgrade from pure `2.0.0` or from some patch `2.0.??`. I'm asking just to narrow the period when the issue could have been introduced - then to search in the Spartacus repo.

Comment: You said "This may be related to this change: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/technical-changes-version-2/#context-change-action-not-dispatched-on-the-initial-setting-of-the-value". I pretty much believe it's not the cause of the problem. This doc describes changes between 1.x and 2.0. But your starting point when upgrading was already 2.0, so the doc seems not relevant.

Comment: We upgraded from the 2.0.0-next.2 version. There the problem didn't occur yet

Comment: Oh, then indeed the mentioned breaking changes doc is relevant for you. 2.0.0-next.2 was released in 2020-03-23 (see https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/6959), but the mentioned breaking change was merged later 2020-04-28 (https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/6901).

Comment: Could you upgrade to the latest patch `2.1.4` and check if the issue still happens?

Comment: I've checkout to branch `release/2.1.1` in Spartacus repo and couldn't reproduce bug in the out-of-the-box application. So what may play the role in your issue are perhaps both breaking changes introduced in 2.0.0 and some customizations in your code around site context and langauges?

Comment: Note: If you run any custom logic related to site context in `APP_INITIALIZER`s or constructors of `@Injectable` Services, then you need to wait until the site context config is intialized, i.e. `await configInit.getStableConfig('context')`

Comment: Upgrading from 2.1.1 to 2.1.4 fixed the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105793/context-not-set-in-time-after-fetching-it-from-the-basesites-request-after-upgra?noredirect=1#comment115131156_65105793): bumping to the latest patch version `2.1.4` has fixed the issue.